# Restart music when a same music is played

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a button and on button press sound "hello" plays.

```
MediaPlayer hello = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKey) {    //i.e on buttonpress
       hello.start();
}
```

this is working fine but when i press the button again the current sound should stop and play again from starting  , at present it wont play any sound at second click on same button .

i tried this way but its not working

```
 MediaPlayer hello = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKey) {    //i.e on buttonpress
hello.stop();           
hello.start();
}
```

searched for similar questions but had a hard luck. How can i achieve it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happen when you use stop() and start() option? I am not sure but I think that you must use prepare() method too. Take a look to this flow: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: how are you doing this? your button has two actions, but there is no obvious separation. Please post the complete code for your button onClick method. Usually, you have to check if the mediaPlayer is playing, if yes, stop it, if no, start it.....

Comment: the sound never plays

Comment: i tried this way too
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKey) {   
    if(hello.isplaying()){
    hello.stop();   
    }        
    hello.start();
    }

Comment: No, please post the complete code....with that example above we cannot see enough context...post it in your question...

Comment: Take a look to my comment I have edit it

Comment: @Nostoraj - with that MediaPlayer.create() method, you don´t need to call prepare()..

Comment: complete code is a little private, the above code should illustrate my problem. i have many buttons in grid view so ,in if condition i am checking if pressed button is of hello or not .if hello button is clicked sound hello should be played and is playing ,but on 2nd quick click on hello button the sound should start again but the sound from the first click still continues.

Comment: when i press hello button 3 times fastly it should say  hehehello  but it just says  hello

Comment: That´s the point, from the above code, it looks like that this are two methods and you are creating a MediaPlayer object everytime. After stop(), you have to reset or better release mediaPlayer and before start again, you have to instantiate MediaPlayer again.So @Vickyexpert is nearly correct, but has forgotten to check if mp is playing.

Comment: thanks this worked for me, edited vickyexpert comment with working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
  MediaPlayer hello = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);

 if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKey) {    //i.e on buttonpress

       hello.reset();
       hello = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
       hello.prepare();
       hello.start();

 }
```

Comment: error at hello=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hello)   
cannot resolve method create'(com.myurl.appname.MainActivity.ButtonclickHandler,int)'

Comment: now this is  working thanks          MediaPlayer hello = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);

 if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonKey) {    //i.e on buttonpress
if(hello.isplaying)
{
       hello.reset();
       hello = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.hello);
      }
       hello.start();

 }